# How to solve an optimization problem with multiple constraints?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I would like to minimize a function in four variables with respect to multiple constraints. $a+b+c+d\leq 1$ and $a, b, c, d \geq 0$, i.e. minimizing on the unit simplex in 4D. How do I incorporate both constraints in my code? I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I haven't seen this discussed anywhere.

```
sol = Minimize[{(a + b - .2)^2 + (c + d - .8)^2 + (a + 
      c - .8)^2 + (b + d - .2)^2 + a + d, a + b + c + d <= 1}, {a, b, 
   c, d}]
```

Comment: Just put all the constraints into the list that is the first argument of `Minimize` (of course, after the objective function).

Comment: `Minimize[{(a + b - 2/10)^2 + (c + d - 8/10)^2 + (a + c - 8/10)^2 + (b + d - 2/10)^2 + a + d, a + b + c + d <= 1, a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0, d >= 0}, {a, b, c, d}]` includes your constraints and returns the following: `{0, {a -> 0, b -> 1/5, c -> 4/5, d -> 0}}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
NMinimize[
 (a + b - 0.2)^2 + (c + d - 0.8)^2 + (a + c - 0.8)^2 + (b + d - 0.2)^2,
 {a, b, c, d} ∈ Simplex[4]
]
```

or alternatively concatenate the multiple constraints using `&&`.